# Gloabal and Local scope confusion, Why is UnboundLocalError not happening?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, global, local, python-multithreading

I am working with WebSocket for a live stream of data and using 2 threads (total  counting MainThread) my confusion is as follows

I have started with a dict live_data which is used to store live data in it

```
smart_soket = soket_plugin(feed_token)

live_data = {}
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=feed_1, name='thread_1',
                            args=(smart_soket, token_string))
thread_1.start()
```

here live_data is updated in function feed_1 which is

```
def feed_1(smart_soket, token_string):
    token=token_string
    task="mw"
    
    def on_message(ws, ticks):
        #print(f"Got a Tick at {dt.datetime.now()}")
        #print(ticks) 
        for stock in ticks:
            try:
                if stock['tk'] == '26009':
                    #print('In for Bank Nifty')
                    live_data[token_to_symbol_map
                              [stock['tk']]] = {"ltp": stock["ltp"],
                                                "Last_update_time": stock["ltt"]}
                else:
                    live_data[token_to_symbol_map
                              [stock['tk']]] = {"ltp": stock["ltp"],
                                                "Last_update_time": stock["ltt"],
                                                "Vwap": stock["ap"]}
            except:
                continue
        
    def on_open(ws):
        print("In on_open")
        print("on open")
        smart_soket.subscribe(task,token)
```

Now my doubt is I have not defined live_data in further code (which if I try to put here will fill the pages ) as a global variable, but when I update live_data in feed_1 it still is getting updated and I am able to use it wherever needed so why is it possible? shouldn't it have given UnboundLocalError?

Comment: So to clarify, `live_data` is defined in module scope, not inside a function definition?

Comment: Thank you sir for your swift reply. I think yes it was defined in module scope (global scope). I am doing this in Jupiter notebook, so I have ran the live_data defining and starting the thread_1 (function feed_1) in one cell, so it will keep running in background. after that, I am using this live data in one other thread and in MainThread.